# Eclipse failed to connect to repositories in Mac Catalina

Tags: eclipse

I have a new `Eclipse` installation and it is missing the `Dynamic web project` section. So I tried to install it from the

```
Help -> Install new software
```

Section.

Then I added the url `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03` there and it failed to connect.

Giving a screenshot of the same below.

[image]

I tried with other urls also. All have the same issue. I am not even able to connect to the `Eclipse market place`.

I am using my home PC and disabled my kaspersky security thinking that it is causing the issue.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Works fine here - macOS 10.15.3 with Eclipse 2020-03. Can Safari get to `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-03`?

Comment: @greg-449, Thanks for taking a look. Yeah. The link is working perfectly in all browsers

Comment: Does [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/) work?